# What you expect/might expect

Tags: phrase-usage

could you please tell me the differences between the words written in bold? Are they both natural and does it convey the same meaning as I want the sentences to give?

- The mobile is nice. Everything is flagship-class except the brightness. In the bright sunlight, the display is surprisingly dimmer than you **expect/might expect**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are generally interchangeable, along with "would expect" (or its contracted form).

The main difference is that the unqualified "you expect" is a direct assumption about someone's thoughts, which should sometimes be avoided, depending on the audience and how universal the presumed expectation is. By contrast, "might expect" and "would expect" simply assert that the expectation would be natural or likely in this situation.

As a style note, the phrase inherently conveys that something is surprising, which makes the word "surprisingly" redundant in your sentence.